# Bevel, Chamfering after holesaw cut

Tags: wood

I would like to cut a hole that is wider on the bottom of the sheet than at the top. So for example using a 60mm holesaw gets me the same diameter on both sides of a 21mm thick sheet. How can I get 60mm on the one side and 70mm or so on the other side, with a flush straight angled surface between the two sides (around 45 degrees).

Doing some googling, I came across beveling but I cant seem to find any large enough bevel or countersink bits. The purpose will be for a spherical object to sit nearly flush on the cut section and slightly protrude on the visible top/front side of the sheet (I have attached a basic image trying to show what I am trying to accomplish).

Any advise appreciated but ideally using the machinery I currently have (drill, table and circular saw, jig saw and grinder).

Please also forgive my lack of terminology here as I am new to this.

[image]

Comment: I think a router fitted with a suitable bit is THE way to do this today, but if you don't have a router you don't have a router. But, all the other methods by which this could be done involve tools you don't list Traditionally this sort of shaping would be done by *reaming*, and you could still do it this way if necessary but you'd need to make the reamer. Because the conical surface is a non-show surface you could do it just by drilling a hole and then enlarging the back of it by carefully paring with a gouge. It's also doable with a suitable rasp or file, although trickier to do neatly.

Comment: @Graphus, thanks for your answer. If anything I learnt a new word in reaming, so will research that a bit more for possible solutions. For now, the unclean way will be a jig saw at 45 degree's and file or chisel as I have those on hand.

Comment: Do practice on a scrap piece when you first try the jigsaw for this! Very tricky cut to do well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's doable with the tools you list.

For really clean and accurate results my choice would be to use a router:

1. Make a hole template in a bit of scrap plywood by drilling a hole with your 60mm holesaw.
2. Make the 60mm hole in your workpiece. You could leave it slightly undersize (1mm or so).
3. Use your template with a 45 degree chamfer router bit with a bottom bearing to cut the bevel. Don't try to hog it all off in one go - take small bites.

If you don't have access to a router you could use a half-round file or rasp if you have a good eye.

Comment: Thank you for your effort in answering. A router is on my to buy list, but for now I have to try work it out with what I have (jig saw at 45 degrees as well as the file might be my only option for now but as you say, the result will not be as clean).